# finding the sum of columns for each row in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I need to find the sum of columns in a every row.

Consider the data set

```
   A,1,5,45,25,20
   B,5,50,5,23,12
   C,1,25,4,15,23
```

I am trying to get the output as below

```
  (A,96)
  (B,95)
  (C,68)
```

I cannot use built in `SUM` function for this. Should I write custom `UDF` or is there any other way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the schema and try the below approach.

**input:**

```
A,1,5,45,25,20
B,5,50,5,23,12
C,1,25,4,15,23
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS(f1:chararray,f2:int,f3:int,f4:int,f5:int,f6:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,SUM(TOBAG(f2..));
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(A,96)
(B,95)
(C,68)
```